Kafka KRaft mode with docker-compose
I am trying to run kafka in KRaft mode, but keep running into errors. Here is my best attempt so far (I used GPT to generate this as I failed to find the relevant parts of the documentation):
docker-compose.yml
services:
  # Kafka controller: manages the overall state of the Kafka cluster
  kafka-controller-0:
    image: apache/kafka:3.7.1
    container_name: kafka-controller-0
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 0
      # Listener for the controller and broker
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9090
      # Port for Raft communication (consensus)
      KAFKA_RAFT_PORT: 9091
      # Directory for Raft and Kafka data
      KAFKA_RAFT_DATA_DIR: /var/lib/kafka/data
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: /var/lib/kafka/data
    volumes:
      - ./data/kafka-controller-0:/var/lib/kafka/data
    ports:
      # expose broker port
      - "9092:9092"
    networks:
      - kafka-net

  # Kafka broker: stores and manages partitions of topics
  kafka-broker-0:
    image: apache/kafka:3.7.1
    container_name: kafka-broker-0
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092
      KAFKA_RAFT_PORT: 9091
      KAFKA_RAFT_DATA_DIR: /var/lib/kafka/data
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: /var/lib/kafka/data
    volumes:
      - ./data/kafka-broker-0:/var/lib/kafka/data
    ports:
      # expose broker port
      - "9093:9092"
    networks:
      - kafka-net

  kafka-broker-1:
    image: apache/kafka:3.7.1
    container_name: kafka-broker-1
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092
      KAFKA_RAFT_PORT: 9091
      KAFKA_RAFT_DATA_DIR: /var/lib/kafka/data
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: /var/lib/kafka/data
    volumes:
      - ./data/kafka-broker-1:/var/lib/kafka/data
    ports:
      - "9094:9092"
    networks:
      - kafka-net

networks:
  kafka-net:

Unfortunately, this gives this error:
Attaching to kafka-broker-0, kafka-broker-1, kafka-controller-0
kafka-controller-0  | ===> User
kafka-broker-0      | ===> User
kafka-broker-0      | uid=1000(appuser) gid=1000(appuser) groups=1000(appuser)
kafka-controller-0  | uid=1000(appuser) gid=1000(appuser) groups=1000(appuser)
kafka-broker-0      | ===> Setting default values of environment variables if not already set.
kafka-controller-0  | ===> Setting default values of environment variables if not already set.
kafka-controller-0  | CLUSTER_ID not set. Setting it to default value: "5L6g3nShT-eMCtK--X86sw"
kafka-broker-0      | CLUSTER_ID not set. Setting it to default value: "5L6g3nShT-eMCtK--X86sw"
kafka-controller-0  | ===> Configuring ...
kafka-broker-0      | ===> Configuring ...
kafka-controller-0  | ===> Launching ... 
kafka-broker-0      | ===> Launching ... 
kafka-broker-0      | ===> Using provided cluster id 5L6g3nShT-eMCtK--X86sw ...
kafka-controller-0  | ===> Using provided cluster id 5L6g3nShT-eMCtK--X86sw ...
kafka-broker-1      | ===> User
kafka-broker-1      | uid=1000(appuser) gid=1000(appuser) groups=1000(appuser)
kafka-broker-1      | ===> Setting default values of environment variables if not already set.
kafka-broker-1      | CLUSTER_ID not set. Setting it to default value: "5L6g3nShT-eMCtK--X86sw"
kafka-broker-1      | ===> Configuring ...
kafka-broker-1      | ===> Launching ... 
kafka-broker-1      | ===> Using provided cluster id 5L6g3nShT-eMCtK--X86sw ...
kafka-broker-0      | Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration `zookeeper.connect` which has no default value. at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.validateValues(KafkaConfig.scala:2299) at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:2290) at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1638) at kafka.tools.StorageTool$.$anonfun$execute$1(StorageTool.scala:71) at scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:283) at kafka.tools.StorageTool$.execute(StorageTool.scala:71) at kafka.tools.StorageTool$.main(StorageTool.scala:52) at kafka.docker.KafkaDockerWrapper$.main(KafkaDockerWrapper.scala:47) at kafka.docker.KafkaDockerWrapper.main(KafkaDockerWrapper.scala)
kafka-controller-0  | Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration `zookeeper.connect` which has no default value. at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.validateValues(KafkaConfig.scala:2299) at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:2290) at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1638) at kafka.tools.StorageTool$.$anonfun$execute$1(StorageTool.scala:71) at scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:283) at kafka.tools.StorageTool$.execute(StorageTool.scala:71) at kafka.tools.StorageTool$.main(StorageTool.scala:52) at kafka.docker.KafkaDockerWrapper$.main(KafkaDockerWrapper.scala:47) at kafka.docker.KafkaDockerWrapper.main(KafkaDockerWrapper.scala)
kafka-broker-1      | Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration `zookeeper.connect` which has no default value. at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.validateValues(KafkaConfig.scala:2299) at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:2290) at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1638) at kafka.tools.StorageTool$.$anonfun$execute$1(StorageTool.scala:71) at scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:283) at kafka.tools.StorageTool$.execute(StorageTool.scala:71) at kafka.tools.StorageTool$.main(StorageTool.scala:52) at kafka.docker.KafkaDockerWrapper$.main(KafkaDockerWrapper.scala:47) at kafka.docker.KafkaDockerWrapper.main(KafkaDockerWrapper.scala)
kafka-controller-0 exited with code 1
kafka-broker-1 exited with code 1
kafka-broker-0 exited with code 1

Adding KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "" to all containers removes this error but induces a new one:
kafka-broker-0      | The kafka configuration file appears to be for a legacy cluster. Formatting is only supported for clusters in KRaft mode.
kafka-broker-1      | The kafka configuration file appears to be for a legacy cluster. Formatting is only supported for clusters in KRaft mode.
kafka-controller-0  | The kafka configuration file appears to be for a legacy cluster. Formatting is only supported for clusters in KRaft mode.

What is the correct way to achieve this, and is there any good documentation that helps me to proceed more systematically?

I am using Kafka to ingest data into #QuestDB and this compose is working for me. I define 2 different brokers/controllers, so I have some common definition at the top and then I include it on both brokers.
(updated): I am also including my configuration for two kafka connect instances and a single schema registry. In a production environment you might want to have more than one schema registry for high availability, and you might want to separate controller and broker roles on the kafka brokers, but hopefully this helps you get started.
Note that I am also including, for your reference, how to automatically register a kafka connect connector on startup. For this to work, you need to have the connector jar (or download from the confluent hub). In my case, I am mounting the local folder ./kafka-connect-plugins, where I have the jar file for the questdb-connect, and then referencing it on the config for the workers. As you see, registration of the connector needs to be done on only one of the kafka connects, and it will be automatically be registered for the rest of workers in the cluster.
# Common kafka broker environment variables
x-kafka-broker-env: &kafka-broker-env
  KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 'CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT'
  KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
  KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
  KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
  KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
  KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
  KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT: yes
  KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: 'broker,controller'
  KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: '1@broker:29093,2@broker-2:29093'
  KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: 'PLAINTEXT'
  KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: 'CONTROLLER'
  KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: '/tmp/kraft-combined-logs'
  KAFKA_METADATA_LOG_DIR: /tmp/kraft-metadata-logs
  # Replace CLUSTER_ID with a unique base64 UUID using "bin/kafka-storage.sh random-uuid"
  # See https://docs.confluent.io/kafka/operations-tools/kafka-tools.html#kafka-storage-sh
  CLUSTER_ID: 'MTkwSDkzMDg5KTdFNDJCRU'


# Common kafka broker configuration
x-kafka-broker-common: &kafka-broker-common
  image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.7.0
  extra_hosts:
    - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"


# Common kafka connect environment variables
x-kafka-connect-env: &kafka-connect-env
  CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092,broker-2:29092'
  CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
  CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 500
  CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
  CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
  CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
  CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
  CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
  CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
  CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
  CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
  CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
  # CLASSPATH required due to CC-2422
  CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-7.5.3-0.jar
  CONNECT_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
  CONNECT_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
  CONNECT_ERRORS_RETRY_TIMEOUT: 90000
  CONNECT_ERRORS_RETRY_DELAY_MAX_MS: 120000
  CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/etc/kafka-connect/jars,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"
  QUESTDB_HTTP_ENDPOINT: "${QUESTDB_HTTP_ENDPOINT:-host.docker.internal:9000}"


# Common kafka connect configuration
x-kafka-connect-common: &kafka-connect-common
  image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:7.7.0
  depends_on:
    - broker-1
    - broker-2
  extra_hosts:
    - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
  volumes:
    - ./kafka-connect-plugins:/etc/kafka-connect/jars


services:
  questdb:
    image: questdb/questdb:8.1.1
    container_name: rta_questdb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8812:8812"
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9009:9009"
      - "9003:9003"
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    environment:
      - QDB_METRICS_ENABLED=TRUE     
    volumes:
      - ./questdb/questdb_root:/var/lib/questdb/:rw

  broker-1:
    <<: *kafka-broker-common
    hostname: broker
    container_name: rta_kafka_broker
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    volumes:
      - ./broker-1/kafka-data:/var/lib/kafka/data
      - ./broker-1/kafka-secrets:/etc/kafka/secrets
      - ./broker-1/tmp:/tmp
    environment:
      <<: *kafka-broker-env
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092'
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,CONTROLLER://broker:29093,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:9092'     

  broker-2:
    <<: *kafka-broker-common
    hostname: broker-2
    container_name: rta_kafka_broker_2
    ports:
      - "9093:9093"
      - "9102:9102"      
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    volumes:     
      - ./broker-2/kafka-data:/var/lib/kafka/data
      - ./broker-2/kafka-secrets:/etc/kafka/secrets
      - ./broker-2/tmp:/tmp
    environment:
      <<: *kafka-broker-env
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 2
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://broker-2:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9093'
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9102
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://broker-2:29092,CONTROLLER://broker-2:29093,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:9093'
      

  schema_registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.7.0
    hostname: schema_registry
    container_name: rta_schema_registry
    depends_on:
      - broker-1
      - broker-2
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema_registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092,broker-2:29092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN: '*'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS: 'GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS'

  kafka-connect-1:
    <<: *kafka-connect-common
    hostname: kafka-connect
    container_name: rta_kafka_connect
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      <<: *kafka-connect-env
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka-connect
      CONNECT_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8083
    command:
    - bash
    - -c
    - |
      # Launch Kafka Connect
      /etc/confluent/docker/run &
      #
      # Wait for Kafka Connect listener
      echo "Waiting for Kafka Connect to start listening on localhost ⏳"
      while : ; do
        curl_status=$$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://localhost:8083/connectors)
        echo -e $$(date) " Kafka Connect listener HTTP state: " $$curl_status " (waiting for 200)"
        if [ $$curl_status -eq 200 ] ; then
          break
        fi
        sleep 5
      done

      echo -e "\n--\n+> Registering QuestDB Connector"

      curl -s -X PUT -H  "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors/questdb-trades/config -d '{
          "connector.class": "io.questdb.kafka.QuestDBSinkConnector",
          "tasks.max": "5",
          "topics": "trades",
          "client.conf.string": "http::addr=${QUESTDB_HTTP_ENDPOINT:-host.docker.internal:9000};",
          "name": "questdb-trades",
          "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
          "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema_registry:8081",
          "include.key": false,
          "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
          "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema_registry:8081",
          "table": "trades",
          "symbols": "symbol, side",
          "timestamp.field.name": "timestamp",
          "value.converter.schemas.enable": true
      }'

       sleep infinity

  kafka-connect-2:
    <<: *kafka-connect-common
    hostname: kafka-connect-2
    container_name: rta_kafka_connect_2
    ports:
      - "8084:8084"
    environment:
      <<: *kafka-connect-env
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka-connect-2
      CONNECT_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8084
 


This seems very close, thanks! But I needed to fix the indentation of questdb:, and after that I still get the error Command [/usr/local/bin/dub path /var/lib/kafka/data writable] FAILED ! when running docker compose up

Also, I would indeed be very interested in an example including schema registry and kafka connect!

Sorry about the indent issue. I removed some part of the docker compose file that were not relevant for you and I broke that in the process! I updated the post to include two instance of kafka connect and one schema registry. This can be tested at this demo project I have available https://github.com/questdb/time-series-streaming-analytics-template

Thanks so much for your continued help! I was able to run this on a friend's Mac, but it crashes on two Ubuntu machines I have access to. Specifically, running docker compose up results in a crash of rta_kafka_broker with messages Command [/usr/local/bin/dub path /var/lib/kafka/data writable] FAILED ! and rta_kafka_broker exited with code 1 (and analogously for rta_kafka_broker_2). Running sudo docker compose up or export DOCKER_COMPOSE_USER_ID=$(id -u) (as suggested in the demo project) did not help...

Sure. That's probably a problem with the broker-1 and broker-2 folder permissions/ownership. Problem probably appears when using sudo, as those folders will be then created with the root user. You can change ownership like
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu broker-*

If the user and group is not ubuntu change accordingly. I will update the instructions on the site :)

Awesome, it works for me now! I had to use sudo docker compose up, Ctrl+C, sudo chown -R myuser:mygroup broker-*, sudo docker compose up. Your updated repo also works for me now. The only thing that does not work is the same using rootless docker, but I believe that is a separate issue...
